# How can I use Scala list on Jruby?

Tags: ruby, scala, jruby

Im trying to use scala code on Jruby. This is my scala code.

```
package test

object JRuby {

  def mystring: String = "This is String"

  def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
    def count(m: Int, c: List[Int]): Int = {
      if (c.isEmpty) 0
      else if (m - c.head == 0) 1
      else if (m - c.head < 0) 0
      else countChange(m - c.head, c) + countChange(m, c.tail)
    }
    count(money, coins)
  }

}
```

And this is my ruby code.

```
require "java"
require "/usr/share/scala/lib/scala-library.jar"

puts Java::test.JRuby.mystring
```

When I try to run my ruby code with "jruby test.rb", it returns error "Unhandled Java exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/immutable/List"

It works well with classpath(jruby -J-cp /usr/share/scala/lib/scala-library.jar test.rb), but I am curious whether I can use this code without classpath or not.

Is there any way?

I'm on Fedora 23 with Scala 2.10.4, JRuby 9.1.2.0 and openjdk 1.8.0_92

-------Solved-------
Work correctly with sbt's assembly plugin

Answer (score 0):

if it does not work than likely not. 
seems that Scala does not like to be put on JRuby's class-path.

the `require .jar` does only append to CP visible by JRuby